# Casting types in a switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I am trying to modularize my type casting. This is my code:

```
export enum detailsDataTypes {
  MACHINE = 'MACHINE',
  USER = 'USER',
  ABSTRACT = 'ABSTRACT',
}

export type sharedTypes = {
  name?: string;
  OEECategory?: string;
  OAECategory?: string;
  color?: string;
  type?: detailsDataTypes;
};

export type AbstractData = sharedTypes & {
  layer: string;
};

export type UserData = sharedTypes & {
  timeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverride: string;
};

export type MachineData = sharedTypes & {
  stateCategory: string;
  timeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverride: string;
  canOverrideOnlyByStates: boolean;
};

type DetailsData = AbstractData | UserData | MachineData;

export const detailsDataCaster = (data: DetailsData): DetailsData | null => {
  switch (data.type) {
    case detailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT:
      return <AbstractData>data;
    case detailsDataTypes.MACHINE:
      return <MachineData>data;
    case detailsDataTypes.USER:
      return <UserData>data;
    default:
      console.log('Wrong data type. Go yell at backend team or check your mocks');
      return null;
  }
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is tell TS that I'm returning `AbstractData` OR `UserData` OR `MachineData` OR `null`. But now, it doesn't like me doing this:

```
export const Details: FC<IDetails> = ({ data: $data = mockUserData }): ReactElement => {
  const data = detailsDataCaster($data);
  switch (data.type) {
    case detailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT:
      return <>Abstract</>;
    case detailsDataTypes.MACHINE:
      return <>Machine</>;
    case detailsDataTypes.USER:
      return <UserDisplay data={data} />; // error is here
    default:
      return <div />;
  }
};
```

Error

```
Type 'DetailsData' is not assignable to type 'UserData'.
  Type 'AbstractData' is not assignable to type 'UserData'.
    Type 'AbstractData' is missing the following properties from type '{ timeout: number; stateAfterTimeout: string; accessCanChoose: string; accessCanOverride: string; }': timeout, stateAfterTimeout, accessCanChoose, accessCanOverride
```

As I understand `|` does not mean OR in TS. I know there is the AND `&`, but this would make no sense. I thought that if I cast, it would be clear as to what I'm returning, but I see it's not so simple. What am I missing?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link, this is an IDE with your code in it)](https://tsplay.dev/Nrvj2N), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing with no unrelated errors (like unimported/undeclared types or values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Your type assertions inside `detailsDataCaster` make no difference to the type inferred for `data`. I think you're trying to create a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) so it can be narrowed by checking `data.type`, but that's not what you have.

Answer (score 2):

If every type extending the `sahredTypes` would specify its own `type` the switch will magically work:

```
export enum detailsDataTypes {
  MACHINE = 'MACHINE',
  USER = 'USER',
  ABSTRACT = 'ABSTRACT',
}

export interface sharedTypes {
  name?: string;
  OEECategory?: string;
  OAECategory?: string;
  color?: string;
  type?: detailsDataTypes;
};

export interface AbstractData extends sharedTypes {
  type: detailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT;

  layer: string;
};

export interface UserData extends sharedTypes {
  type: detailsDataTypes.USER;

  timeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverride: string;
};

export interface MachineData extends sharedTypes {
  type: detailsDataTypes.MACHINE;

  stateCategory: string;
  timeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverride: string;
  canOverrideOnlyByStates: boolean;
};

type DetailsData = AbstractData | UserData | MachineData;
```

[Playgound link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCbBgQwJYA2AzgCI64AqAnmMEXAN4BQccAsgIIDCAEgJIA5AKJwAvHADknXoKESANCzgBVAMpCASmMlrNCpRwBCqihu4VtEoybNcK%20gL5MmoSLDh5EMYFABmOAGNgOCIACxwoYAxqWnpmVkQcVGAAfgAuEJgoTwBzAG4lAHkhIS5yYBzoKnTM7MR8oo5S8sqoaoyiLNyC1gCIAmgazrqG1hgaVIysXEJSchwYugKHApdwaHhPbz9A4I4AI2HAmDJcBBBvRAx6MIioxbilcdop7HxiU4WJogA6a1NzKtWAQcFQfB0uvVlqtXBsPF4fP4gioiD5PudLtcQuFItFvownhNXjMPvMHj9dBogXAYHhkhBkDAMihUPsfD1MuUOL5thQ6cAGUzat0lIEgkQiGVEFxQhAIKiISMOWK6JKcIhCgA3HzZLCKkUrZyw9xbRG7diBUKeYDo0CYm44%2074%20I0omYN6zT7k6T8YTUzrlMreVpUfVQp78wXMtBsqAcgPebm8yOMsOjOAqiVSmVyhXC8OsTNqjXaqC64BpjkBdVanV4LCFRAEKiGKiqXDeIgZfZygjAdXQ5zPYIkD2ks7iA5HAIneZwAA%20KLRc8XbEt1s%20MPW7j6iE67pJc1wZU6Pm0AAoMPMMqPD58AJQ3sdHnALuAoAgEMQAPgJrCIADueAwAEoRwJe8w-MO95-qwcDVqiB7vC%205L-LYFBpEocHwRAe79MAPwDDkEG4IRoI%20PeHLYZEMDIFAiCYPM1K9DgiHTMhXrfD8PqyJh2G9LhRD4YREDEVepEJsAQYVFUlFYXBNF0Qx4k4Mx8GscE7GemSXGUnx-G7kJfYiWJkFFlKtZlvWwByfxcAAPT2YZwlESROBkWCUCUQ59lwEIZbQPJrCKfRjG4FR7r%20MgBBMkFOF4cZrkSAA6lAuE5GFr7Dj8cAAOIQHAYKfhm8D7IEADWSAYDS-boNA8GhMAATlYVDJQHAqAQM1RASLZ-EhQxH4EByTgrEAA) that shows the type is correctly inferred from the switch.

Comment: Is there a reason to leave `type?: detailsDataTypes;` in `sharedTypes` in this case?

Comment: Yes, if something is shared type, you can detect it’s type

Comment: But if we're already putting the type in each interface, why do we need it in shared as well?

Comment: If you ever assign a variable type of `sharedTypes` it would be beneficial, but you don't need it in the parent. Even more, if you only share the `DetailsData` in the rest of the app. I just like to have it there, nothing else

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add a discriminant value to each type like this...

```js
export type AbstractData = sharedTypes & {
  layer: string;
  type: detailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT; // add this field, it can only be of this literal value
};

export type UserData = sharedTypes & {
  timeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverride: string;
  type: detailsDataTypes.USER; // add this field
};

export type MachineData = sharedTypes & {
  stateCategory: string;
  timeout: number;
  stateAfterTimeout: string;
  accessCanChoose: string;
  accessCanOverride: string;
  canOverrideOnlyByStates: boolean;
  type: detailsDataTypes.MACHINE; // add this field
};

type DetailsData = AbstractData | UserData | MachineData;
function Details(data: DetailsData) {
    switch (data.type) {
        case detailsDataTypes.ABSTRACT:
            data; // data is AbstractData
            break;
            
        case detailsDataTypes.MACHINE:
            data; // data is MachineData
            break;

        case detailsDataTypes.USER:
            data; // data is UserData
            break;

        default:
            data; // data is never (no more possibilities left!)
            break;
    }
}
```

This technique is called [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).